# What is a good replacement for "ununderstandable"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, negation, prefixes

I want to tell a colleague of mine I'm doing something that will prevent her from getting "ununderstandable" errors. I have:

> ...so that you will not get unnecessary, [ununderstandable] errors.

After googling "ununderstandable", I see that there is no such word, but I'm still looking for something that sounds better.

Comment: Surely, that would be "Derstandable"! (j/k)

Comment: @KazDragon +Your joke was ununderstandable to many here.

Comment: Overstandable..

Answer (score 49, accepted):

How about [*incomprehensible*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incomprehensible) or [*unfathomable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfathomable)?

Comment: *Incomprehensible* is the one.

Comment: *Incomprehensible* is the first one that came to me as well.

Comment: *Incomprehensible* is good, as so is the second, though it should be reserved for stronger cases.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer **unintelligible**.

Answer (score 15):

*Enigmatic*, *abstruse*, *obscure* or *cabalistic* sound good to me.

Comment: To be honest, I already sent the mail, but I'll definitely use "obscure" next time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

> ...so that you will not get
>   unnecessary **cryptic** error messages.

Comment: *cryptic* is ununderstandable to many.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendations are:

- *difficult-to-understand* or *impossible-to-understand*
- *opaque*
- *obtuse*

Answer (score 1):

How about hyphenation: non-understandable?

Answer (score 1):

I googled it, and here it is in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ununderstandable).

**ununderstandable**

un·un·der·stand·a·ble {uhn-uhn-der-stan-duh-buhl}

–adjective

*incapable of being understood, failing to be understood correctly.*

My Commentary:

*I LOVE some of the answers.  What a cool sight.   The English language continues to evolve.  Every year new grammar rules are created.  To this board of Deciders I would suggest that if a word is google-able, then it should be able to be published.  I guess it is ultimately the author's choice, depending on what is being writ.  I am also of the kind of wordsmith [get-sic] that Likes to makeUp rules and Words.*

*"Being brain injured, the challenges we face are inexplicable, or at least, ununderstandable."*

blog entry essay with ["UNUNDERSTANDABLE"](http://bit.ly/UBkRnU)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose indecipherable will be an acceptable replacement.

Answer (score 1):

How about abstract? 
If you look at: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abstract
Under full definition and in part b, it talks about how abstract means difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon this having had cause to research the word myself.

It's not something that I'd use myself as I think it sounds clumsy and, as has already been demonstrated here, there are better alternatives. But, I'd argue that it is a perfectly valid word.

An [ngram viewer](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22ununderstandable%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1924,cd_max:1948&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=6RAPV_zcN6OQmgXUq67ABg#q=%22ununderstandable%22%20schopenhauer) search shows it (and 'ununderstood') in use for the last 200 years with many of the examples coming from some fairly heavyweight sources. Schopenhauer is a name that springs out from the list as a user.

For me though, the OED is the ultimate arbitrator in questions of legitimate usage:

> *ununderstandable, adj.*
>
> a1631   J. Donne Serm. (1958) IX. 51   Let him have
>   known..In-intelligibilia, In-investigabilia, (as Tertullian speakes)
>   un-understandable things, unrevealed decrees of God.
>
> a1843   R. Southey Common-place Bk. (1849) 2nd Ser. 251/2   The vile
>   and ununderstandable Machabeo he ranks with Homer and Virgil!
>
> 1872   B. Brierley Cotters of Mossburn xxiv. 252   There is something
>   very ‘ununderstandable’ going on between Luke Brundrett and Miss
>   Louisa Gerrard.
>
> 1891   H. Herman His Angel 46   He stammered a few un-understandable
>   words.

Answer (score -1):

[*Misunderstandable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misunderstandable)?

Comment: different meaning: "can be misunderstood" isn't "can't be understood".

Answer (score -1):

The word *ununderstandble* is noted in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ununderstandable) though!

Comment: I personally never cite Wiktionary because there are huge gaps in their scholarship. You can't conclude anything from the existence of this entry. A good starting point for reputable references is OneLook.com (but it also links to some unreliable references such as Urban Dictionary).